# Need help understanding d3js exit selection

Tags: d3.js

I am having trouble understanding d3js's exit selection.  My understanding is that if you remove data from your dataset, and call remove then d3 will find the elements on the page that no longer exist in your dataset and remove them.  I have created a fiddle to illustrate my problem:

```
d3.selectAll('relevantElement').data(updatedData).exit().remove()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acuevas15/f9PRd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit selection works as it should, it's the matching that doesn't work as you expect. The reason for that is that by default, it matches elements using their index. That is, the first element in the data array matches the first DOM element, the second the second and so on.

What you probably want to do is match by *content* and not index. You can do that by supplying a key function that tells D3 how to match:

```
d3.selectAll('p').data([3,4], function(d) { return d; }).exit().remove();
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9PRd/1/).

Comment: Thanks Lars, your response was quick and correct.  I was confused as I assumed that data binding always matched data to elements by identity and not index.  Now my graph is back on track.